# openerp v 5.0.16 when OpenERP Web is run getting error, How to resolve?

Tags: openerp

```
openerp@ubuntu-10:~$ **openerp-web** 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/openerp-web", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in 
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Beaker>=1.1
```

We have installed with Python 2.6 and almost all dependency resolved.

Can any one highlight where is the issue?

Thanks

Atul

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `beaker` python package.

You can install this with

```
sudo apt-get install python-beaker
```

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11788373/3665278) question on StackOverflow if you already have beaker installed (via easy_install or pip) you may want to do

```
easy_install --upgrade beaker
```

Comment: It works, I did the same thing yesterday but was not going through but today somehow it worked.